# Register user.. button not showing

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

This is Worklight server 5.0.5.

In the Worklight Applicater Center, under Users/Groups tab, the Register user ... button is not showing when I clicked on "Regsitered Users" selection on the left panel.  Any idea?

Note that I do see Create group... button though when I clicked on "User Groups" selection on the left panel.

Answer (score 2):

If the Worklight Application Center is configured to use LDAP, this button is not displayed.
As a matter of fact, in that case, users are directly retrieved from the LDAP.
Otherwise this button should be displayed to register users declared in the server.

Hopes this helps,

Damien